# Basic topology : boundary of a set

Tags: general-topology

I'am trying to solve this problem :

Let the subset :
$$\{(x,y) \in R^2:y\geq 0,y\leq x\leq4-y\}$$
Find the boundary of this subset.

I know the definition of the boundary of a subset but it is hard for me to apply it here... Does someone has any method to solve this kind of problem ?

I have an other question, does someone know where can i find exercices like this in order to improve my skills ?

Thank you,

Comment: Draw the set...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry, I have to find the boundary of this subset.

Comment: Martin-Blas my intuiton says that it is a triangle, but a don't know in this case how to find the $3$ lines that define this triangle...

Comment: The three lines that define the triangle is 

$$y=x$$

$$y=4-x$$

$$y=0$$

Comment: Okay so for each inequality, we take the equality and we get the boundary is that right ?

Comment: Yes, I suppose the verification becomes immediately trivial if you draw the set (as suggested by Martín)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so we can picture the elements of this set as lying in 2-dimensional space.

Each of the elements must satisfy $y \geq 0$ and $y \leq x \leq 4 - y$, which we can break down further into three inequalities:

$$y \geq 0$$
$$y \leq x$$
$$y \leq 4-x$$

Just plot the lines $y=0$, $y=x$ and $y=4-x$ on the plane and you will have a triangle. The points lying inside this triangle are in the set, and the lines themselves define the boundary of the set.

Comment: Thank you that is clear !